# How to bind properties to input fields from selectoin box selection

Tags: angularjs

Can't figure out how to bind the properties of a object with this select box. 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IuNC31Pf4fc104ubc1Xr?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="currentEmployee.FirstName" ng-options="employee.EmployeeId as employee.FirstName for employee in employees" ng-change="change(employee)">
  <option value="">-- Select Employee</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="currentEmployee.LastName" />


$scope.change = function(employee) {
  $scope.currentEmployee.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
   $scope.currentEmployee.LastName = employee.LastName;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you don't need to use `ng-change`.

Set the `ng-model` to be the actual employee object and bind it to `$scope.currentEmployee`.

```
<select ng-model="currentEmployee" 
        ng-options="employee.FirstName for employee in employees">
   <option value="">-- Select Employee</option>
</select>
```

Then, you could bind `currentEmployee` to `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="currentEmployee.LastName" />
```

Oh, and if you want you "-- Select Employee" to appear first, set `$scope.currentEmployee = "";` in the controller.

Here's your modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dxby4sBZQbcoZYSbHMvU?p=preview)